# How to make an Ajax Post Back with ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-post, partial-views

I am very new to MVC . So , have been studying the code of MusicStore Application in CodePlex.

I am unable to understand what does the following code meant:

```
 // AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            // Remove the item from the cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
            string albumName = storeDB.Carts
                .Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Album.Title;

            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

            // Display the confirmation message
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(albumName) +
                    " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };

            return Json(results);
        }

        //
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CartSummary()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();

            return PartialView("CartSummary");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me clarify , how that particluar HttpPost works as a Ajax Post back .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use jQuery Ajax to make an asynchronous postback request

please see the code below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: @Url.Action("RemoveFromCart"),
  data: ({
            Id:1
         }),
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
})
```

**[HttpPost]** -- attribute ensures that **RemoveFromCart** action method accepts only post requests

**[ChildActionOnly]** -- attribute ensures that an action method can be called only as a child method from within a view. These are typically associated with partial views.

Comment: Which view engine is better to use Razor or Aspx ? what control is used for Partial view incase of ASPX view engine

Comment: Hi Avinash, If we consider minor things Razor is better than ASPX.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I came across it in my searches and to get this to work I had to add quotes around the Url.Action.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "@(Url.Action("RemoveFromCart"))",
      data: ({
                Id:1
             }),
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    })
```